# ignoring second scanf?

Tags: go, scanf

I've been having an issue with Go but I'm not sure if it's my fault or the compiler's fault. For a bit of background info, I know how to program in C and decided to jump onto Go since I have lots of free time.

While on it I noticed that when I put 2-3 scanf's in a row, it usually ignores at least one. How come that happens? Code below. Thank you!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var day, month, age int32

    fmt.Println("What's your day of birth?")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &day)
    fmt.Println("What's your month of birth?")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &month)
    fmt.Println("What's your age?")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &age)

}
```

EDIT: The outcome is

What's your day of birth?

(I can enter a number)

What's your month of birth?

What's your age?

(I can enter a number)

Comment: According to the docs: "Newlines in the input must match newlines in the format.". Change your formats to include \n.

Comment: @Burak Serdar Thank you man! It worked like a charm.